# Maximum number of devices an Android can handle from USB hub

Tags: usb, usb-on-the-go

We are planning to work with multiple USB devices from a tablet.

For this implementation, we are planning to connect a HUB (http://www.amazon.in/Belkin-F4U041SA-7-Ports-Hi-Speed-Powered/dp/B008368G72) to it via OTG.

My queries:

1. Will there be any issues in kernel device detection?
2. Will power be an bigger issue?

Also, request to suggest some more failures using this mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

As it's a powered hub, power won't be a problem. Android doesn't have a specific limit on how many USB devices you can have, so the limit is that imposed by the USB specification. If I remember rightly, it's 256 devices, but you can check that for yourself if you're worried. Using a single USB hub with a device is well-tested on different kinds of devices.

The only other thing you need to check is that the tablet you're using supports USB-OTG. Most branded devices do these days, but cheaper tablets from unknown manufacturers, and older ones, don't. You also need Android 4.0.3 or later.